# Unable to throw a `checked` exception when using Java Optional ifPresentOrElse method

Tags: java, exception, option-type, java-9, java-11

Why a checked Exception can't be thrown in the orElse part when using `ifPresentOrElse` java Optional method ?

For example:

```
dao.findBook(id).ifPresentOrElse(book -> {
    printingService.print(book, printerName);
    changeBookPrintDate(book.getId(), LocalDateTime.now());
}, () -> new BookNotFoundException());
```

where `BookNotFoundException` is a custom exception extending `Exception` class (checked exception).

but this code makes the compiler upset:

```
unreported exception com...exception.BookNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

(knowing that it is already thrown in the method declaration, and surrounding this block with try catch doesn't resolve the compilation problem).

But if we make `BookNotFoundException` to be extending `RuntimeException` (which is unchecked), then all works perfectly.

Anyone knows why ?

What's the reason that prevents throwing such kind of exceptions in this java 9 Optional method ?

And why should I make my exception a RuntimeException to make it works while it is more to be considered a '*custom exception*' more than it is '*runtime*' ?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726874/why-cant-i-throw-an-exception-in-a-java-8-lambda-expression) is addressing the same problem but for java 8 lambdas, so I don't know if the same applies for java 9 Optionals.

Other [researches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302015/throw-checked-exceptions) leaded nowhere other than confirming that [it is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503870/how-to-handle-an-exception-inside-of-ifpresent).

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 26):

You must enclose the throw within curly braces:

```
*() -> { throw new BookNotFoundException(); }*
```

Answer (score 17):

The method `ifPresentOrElse` is a useful tool when you want to specify two non-throwing actions, so that you can continue after the method invocation in either case. But when you want to throw in the case of absent values, it’s an unnecessary complication. Just use

```
var book = dao.findBook(id).orElseThrow(BookNotFoundException::new);
printingService.print(book, printerName);
changeBookPrintDate(book.getId(), LocalDateTime.now());
```

Since this construct will throw for an absent value, the code flow will only continue for present values. So you can use `book` in the follow-up code like an ordinary local variable, but with the guaranty that it will never be `null`.

The method [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) expects a `Supplier` for the exception to be thrown, instead of a function that throws. That way, the supplier can construct a checked exception without throwing it and the generic signature of [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) declares to throw whatever type the supplier produced.

> `public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow​(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I can use orElseThrow as you said, but my question was exactly on java-9 `ifPresentOrElse` which works for unchecked exceptions in the case of absent values, but not with checked ones. So just to understand why and if there is an alternative provided in java9 Optionals. Thanks

Comment: The technical reason is that you are passing a `Runnable` and its `run()` method does not declare any checked exceptions, hence, you cannot throw checked exceptions. The semantic reason, to use a `Runnable` which doesn’t support checked exceptions, has been given in the answer; it is not the intended use case. The alternative, the intended way to use it, has also been given in the answer already.